# Modifying the scoring of a quiz app (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Context about the app:

This is a sample 5 question test app that I made while I also learned firebase database just yesterday.
The app is working perfectly and it does it needs to do, BUT what I wanna do next is that there are no right answers and each button corresponds to a score

ex:
Question: What are you feeling out of 1-5

A.)1 - I am feeling bad
B.)2 - I am feeling sad
C.)3 - neutral
D.)4 - I am feeling happy
E.)5 -  I am feeling good

As you can see here if the user answers E for example then he gets 5 pts (the points is not shown) and the user will get 1 point if he answers A and so on...

code:

```
{
    private TextView mScoreView;
    private int questionNumber = 0;
    private TextView mQuestion, result;
    private Button choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,quit;
    private int nScore = 0;
    private String ans;
    private Firebase question,c1,c2,c3,c4,answer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maths2);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c1);
        choice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c2);
        choice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c3);
        choice4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c4);
        quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit);


        updateQuestion();



        quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Maths2.this,MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });






//CHOICE 1//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice1.getText().equals(ans)) {
                    nScore = nScore + 1;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                }else
                    {
                        updateQuestion();

                }

            }
        });
        //CHOICE 1 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //CHOICE 2//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        choice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice2.getText().equals(ans)) {
                    nScore = nScore + 2;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                }else
                {
                    updateQuestion();

                }

            }
        });
        //CHOICE 2 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //CHOICE 3//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        choice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice3.getText().equals(ans)) {
                    nScore = nScore + 3;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                }else
                {
                    updateQuestion();

                }

            }
        });
        //CHOICE 3 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //CHOICE 4//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        choice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice4.getText().equals(ans)) {
                    nScore = nScore + 4;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                }else
                {
                    updateQuestion();

                }

            }
        });
        //CHOICE 4 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    }
    private void updateScore (int score){
       mScoreView.setText("" + nScore);
    }





    private void updateQuestion() {

        question = new Firebase("https://thesis-e4f56-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"+ questionNumber + "/question");
        question.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String question = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mQuestion.setText(question);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }





        });
        c1= new Firebase("https://thesis-e4f56-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"+ questionNumber + "/choice1");
        c1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        choice1.setText(choice);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
        c2= new Firebase("https://thesis-e4f56-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"+ questionNumber +"/choice2");
        c2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                choice2.setText(choice);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });


        c3= new Firebase("https://thesis-e4f56-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"+ questionNumber +"/choice3");
        c3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                choice3.setText(choice);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        c4= new Firebase("https://thesis-e4f56-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"+ questionNumber +"/choice4");
        c4.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                choice4.setText(choice);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        answer = new Firebase( "https://thesis-e4f56-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"+questionNumber+"/answer");
        answer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ans = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        if (nScore == 10) {

            result.setText("good job");

        }
        questionNumber ++;


    }
}
```

I am doing this since yesterday and I also just learned doing firebase yesterday. I just got stumped for the past hour on what the logic is.

Comment: You said that there are no right answer but inside the click of each choice you are doing `choice4.getText().equals(ans)`. Could you please tell what this logic is for?

Comment: The code is still the working quiz app. When I read your comment I just thought of something. What this code does is that it gets the button picked and compares with the answer from the database, yes? If I just delete that line and continue with the nscore = nscore +3 then it should be fine right?

Comment: Ya it should be.

Comment: Thanks bro I just did it like this:
nScore = nScore +2;
                updateScore(nScore);

                updateQuestion();

I got rid of the if statement.

Comment: I wrote an updated answer, hope it helps you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the condition `choice4.getText().equals(ans)` inside all the `choice` click listeners. You should also put the code in a common method.

```
public void handleChoiceClicked(){
 nScore = nScore + 2;
 updateScore(nScore);
 updateQuestion();
}
```

call it from the click listeners rather than duplicating them.

```
           choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    handleChoiceClicked();
                }
            });
            //CHOICE 1 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //CHOICE 2//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            choice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    handleChoiceClicked();
                }
            });
            //CHOICE 2 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //CHOICE 3//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            choice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    handleChoiceClicked();
                }
            });
            //CHOICE 3 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //CHOICE 4//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            choice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    handleChoiceClicked();
                }
            });
```